# How to inspect your code on what causing API errors with facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Hello I created a php page where I use facebook API. The page was running fine 2 months ago so I didnt check it again.

I continued yesterday to code the page, however I found out that my page that handles facebook admin pages ask me to reauthenticate.

Some of the features of the pages are accessible and working great but that specific page does not.

I guess its something that must be changed from facebook but I cant guess what. Where should I start to find the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Have you updated your PHP SDK...the SDK changed a few days back

Comment: @AnveshSaxena No I haven't. May you point me to a direction please?

Comment: Its available [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)... You can also see that Facebook made changes to a few files

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put your facebook API calls in `try` `catch` statements. so that within `catch` block you can log the error message to error logs. something like:

```
try{
  $facebook->api("/me");
}catch (Exception $e){
  error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```